# Error "'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'" but it's a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a function that returns a list of songs in a playlist, but i don't know why is returning the error "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'", i tried to define as a list but it's not working yet, can somebody help show me where is the error?

```
def play_song():
filenames = []
filenames = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir = "C:/Python/Playlist/", title = "Please choose the songs", filetypes=(("Mp3 Files", "*.mp3"),))
for song in filenames:
    filenames = filenames.replace("C:/Python/Playlist/", "")
    filenames = filenames.replace("*.mp3", "")
    Playlist_box.insert(END,filenames)
```

Comment: `filedialog.askopenfilenames` returns tuple. Not that if it is a list `replace ` method will yield the result you [seems to]  expect - i.e. remove path and extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a list, you need to convert the value to a list

```
filenames = list(filedialog.askopenfilenames(...))
```

Assigning an empty list to it beforehand does nothing, as the empty list will be replaced with a tuple immediately after.